# Регистрация через Facebook кнопку. Android.

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-api, facebooksdk, facebook-graph-api

Как можно зарегистрировать пользователя по кнопке Facebook, чтоб считать введенные данные и отправить их на сервер. 
Вот пользователь введет данные на странице логина в фейсбук. И Как после можно отправить запрос

`APIService.doSignUp(String username, String password)` с данными, которые ввел пользователь.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Инициализируете `Facebook SDK` и регестрируете `callback`  :

```
public void initFacebookSdk() {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(activity.getApplicationContext());
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        Log.d("Success", "Login");
                        Log.d(TAG, "Facebook getApplicationId: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getApplicationId());
                        Log.d(TAG, "Facebook getToken: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
                        Log.d(TAG, "Facebook getUserId: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId());
                        Log.d(TAG, "Facebook getExpires: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getExpires());
                        Log.d(TAG, "Facebook getLastRefresh: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getLastRefresh());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Login Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, exception.getMessage());
                    }
                });

    }
```

После этого делаете вызов активити для логина

```
public void callLoginActivity() {
    LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
    loginManager.setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK);
    loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(
            activity,
            Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "read_custom_friendlists"));
}
```

в результате вам в метод `onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)`  вернуться данные, после чего вы уже сможете делать остальные запросы о данных пользователя с полученным `token`.

После того как вы получаете токен вы можете запрашивать его так:

```
/**
 * Get current user access token by Facebook
 *
 * @return - instance of current {@link com.facebook.AccessToken}
 */
public AccessToken getAccessToken() {
    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
        System.out.println("not logged in yet");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Logged in");
    }
    return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
}
```

Далее если вы хотите получить какие то данные профиля пользователя от Facebook -  вы делаете запрос к `Graph Api`, вот , на пример запрос который вернет вам данные такие, как имя,id,avatar:

```
/**
 * GraphApi request for get device user info
 * from Facebook as: id, name, avatar
 */
public void getMeInfo() {

    AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
            token,
            PATH_ME,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                    JSONObject object; //raw response json object
                    JSONObject pictureData; //json object which contains picture data

                    try {

                        //check is response is not empty
                        if (response.getError() == null){

                            //parse json 
                            object = new JSONObject(response.getRawResponse().toString());
                            pictureData = object.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data");

                            long id = Long.parseLong(object.optString("id");
                            String name = object.getString("name");
                            String url = pictureData.optString("url");
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

    //request params
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,picture.type(large)");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}
```

Все остальные запросы к `GraphApi` делаются подобным образом.
Вот ссылка на [документацию](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference) и ссылка на [Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)
, в нем вы можете протестить запросы и в нем же можно сгенерировать код этого запроса для своего приложения, т.е. вы просто скопируете его себе в приложение и сможете его использовать, это очень удобно.

Comment: а как нибудь нельзя это сделать на одной странице? Если можно, то как? Я хотел бы делать все так, чтоб вот пользователь нажимает кнопку "Вход через Facebook " и он вводит и после чего, сделать свой запрос с username и каким нибудь случайным паролем. После этого запроса, его автоматом перекинет на полный доступ приложением.

Comment: Можете переформулировать вопрос, я не до конца вас понимаю?

Comment: как можно, весь код на одной странице отобразить, а то я в этом деле новичок. И как правильно вытаскивать usename, email. Не могли бы вы подробно описать, если вам не трудно.

Comment: @SatanistDevilov обновил ответ

Comment: Огромное спасибо тебе)

Answer (score 1):

[Вот документация по авторизации через facebook.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android)

После авторизации можно получить информацию вида: такой пользователь существует, всё в порядке и токен, разрешающий работать с facebook api, например прочитать профиль пользователя.

Пароль при этом получен не будет, facebook api предоставит вам только логин и токен. Пароль можно сгенерировать или же использовать токен вместо него.

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
// If using in a fragment
loginButton.setFragment(this);    
// Other app specific specialization

// Callback registration
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // App code
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        // App code
    }
});
```

Comment: а как правильно брать логин и токен хотя-бы. В документации не могу найти.(

Comment: `@Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
        }` - В loginResult хранится токен итд